# How can I convert path containing wildcard to corresponding file entries in C program?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I'm trying to implement the `ls` command with wildcard, `*`.
I have just learned the fact that most shells convert ls-argument containing `*` to the corresponding entries when performing `ls` command.
For example, The directory `foo` consist of `a.file`, `b.file`, and directory `bar`.
Then, the directory `bar` has `c.file`, `d.file`, and `e.file`.
and assume that current directory is the directory `foo`.

the argument `*/*` is converted is to the following entries.

```
"bar/c.file", "bar/d.file", "bar/e.file"
```

How can program perform this? I don't know where to start from. And
there are many possible cases.

`*/../*`, `../../*`, `*/*/*`, etc.

Any advice would be awesome. Thank you..

Comment: http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/09/ls-command-implementation-for-linuxunix.html

Comment: Read about the [`glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/glob.html) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of couse use [`glob()`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/glob) to do a lot of this work.

Such patterns are called [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), for some reason I won't dig up now. :)

Answer (score 1):

POSIX provides [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) for programmatic wildcard path expansion.